# "use of unassigned local variable" error when passing ref parameter

Tags: c#

This code generates the error:

> used of unassigned local variable 'namespace2'

```
XNamespace namespace2;
string partText = Declaration.partText;
Declaration.partText = string.Empty;
string str = "";
IEnumerable<XElement> source = InputXDoc.Descendants(Function.GetNamespace(ref namespace2, "").GetName("body"));
if (source.Descendants<XElement>(Function.GetNamespace(ref namespace2, "").GetName("div")).Count<XElement>() > 0)
{
    IEnumerable<XElement> introduced5 = InputXDoc.Descendants(Function.GetNamespace(ref namespace2, "").GetName("body"));
    if (introduced5.Descendants<XElement>(Function.GetNamespace(ref namespace2, "").GetName("div")).First<XElement>().Attributes("id").Count<XAttribute>() > 0)
    {
        IEnumerable<XElement> introduced6 = InputXDoc.Descendants(Function.GetNamespace(ref namespace2, "").GetName("body"));
        this.ChapterName = introduced6.Descendants<XElement>(Function.GetNamespace(ref namespace2, "").GetName("div")).First<XElement>().Attributes("id").First<XAttribute>().Value;
    }
}
```

Why did I encounter this?

Comment: Seems to me the error message is pretty clear. You didn't include the line number here, but I'm sure the compiler is reporting it to you. So you should know exactly where the error is occurring. And you can see for yourself that you never initialize `namespace2`. Unfortunately, you haven't provided enough information for us to know _how_ the variable should be initialized.

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) for `ref`:

> An argument that is passed to a ref parameter must be initialized
>   before it is passed. This differs from out parameters, whose arguments
>   do not have to be explicitly initialized before they are passed. For
>   more information, see out.

so you need to write:

```
XNamespace namespace2 = null;
```

Its always good practice to initialize your variables anyways!

**Note:** I initialized to `null` because I don't know what your parameter *actually* needs to be initialized to. Check the documentation for the function you are calling, you will likely need it to be something else.

Comment: That will fix the compiler error, no doubt. But is it really what the OP needs to do? Are you sure that `Function.GetNamespace()` does not require the argument to be non-null? `ref` arguments are usually `ref` instead of `out` specifically because the method expects them to have a usable value to start with.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I have no idea. I would have expected it to be initialized to something else, but without knowing the inner workings of the called functions I can't say for sure. I'll edit to mention it though.

Comment: @PeterDuniho  here is ref that I call..

   public static XNamespace GetNamespace(ref XNamespace xns, string ns)
        {
            if (xns == null)
            {
                xns = XNamespace.Get(ns);
            }
            return xns;
        }

Thanks alot.

Comment: @LuluErwin I'm not familiar with the correct initialization for `XNamespace`, hopefully peter can help. Also, you don't need to notify me. Its my post, so I'm *always* notified.

Comment: @LuluErwin: based on that code, initializing to `null` certainly is _legal_ and would probably work for you. But now I don't understand why you have that method at all; you could just init the variable as `XNamespace namespace2 = "";` and be done with it. It's also odd to see all that `Xml.Linq` code where instead of taking advantage of the fluent syntax designed into the types, you're doing things so explicitly. Type inference, implicit operators, and using e.g. `Attribute()` instead of `Attributes()` would make the code so much easier to write and read.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, Thanks Peter, I think I will just revise my code, and make it simpler, I just borrow that class from a friend, to make it easier, sad to say it creates more problem in my coding.